# .htacess Serve from different directory for Mobile Users

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an adoptive website where Desktop has different pages and the Mobile set has different pages. So the same URL `mywebsite.com` should serve from the different directory if the request is coming from Mobile.

So the URL should be the same for Desktop and Mobile Users, if its desktop root directory will be served, but for Mobile user, it should serve from a different directory say `/mobile`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android |iPhone|iPod [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !reset [NC]
// Serve from different directory
```

Any help would much be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a rule like this in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# use user agent to detect a mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule !^mobile/ mobile%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```